# MySQL Search multiple columns without OR

Tags: mysql, select, multiple-columns

I've got a page that builds up a really long query depending on `$_POST` variables. The reason I'm trying to do this without MySQL's `OR` is because I'd have to restate the entire query just to alter one small parameter at the end, which seems like a waste of resources.

This is my pseudo-query:

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE 
person = '$var1' AND
place = '$var2' AND
location_a = '$var3' AND
location_b = '$var3'
```

If I were to use `OR`, this fat ugly query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE 
person = '$var1' AND
place = '$var2' AND
location_a = '$var3' OR

person = '$var1' AND
place = '$var2' AND
location_b = '$var3'
```

Is there a way to search both `location_a` and `location_b` for `$var3` without using `OR`?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but the first condition DON'T match the second.... or there is something that I missed?

Comment: Just letting you know in case you don't already, you don't want to put user input (stuff from $_POST $_GET or the like) in the query without properly sanitizing it. Check out mysql_real_escape_string() or PDO for more info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use parantheses:

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE 
person = '$var1' AND
place = '$var2' AND
(
location_a = '$var3' OR location_b = '$var3'
)
```

Actually I don't get your question. You don't have to restate your whole query. Maybe you show your code? And what's so bad about `OR`? Just use parantheses.

Comment: It was my misunderstanding of the proper syntax. Your answer cleared things up for me and works. Thanks.